# C# Calculator (Text Based Calculator)

Tags: c#, string, integer, converters, calculator

Don't know how to convert String to int.
I tried to replace the String type with a int but it wouldn't execute if I did.
And when I tried to convert the String types to other things like double, float, bool, char etc.

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What operation would you like? + - * /: ");
            String Operator = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Type first number: ");
            String num1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Type second number: ");
            String num2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Operator == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
            }
            if (Operator == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
            }
            if (Operator == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
            }
            if (Operator == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To convert a string to an int, use int.Parse()

Comment: Either `int.Parse`, or *better* `int.TryParse` (which allow you to catch format errors - when use inputs, say `bla-bla-bla`)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `string num1 = Console.ReadLine();` use `int num1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Do this for `num2` also. Keep in mind that if you input an invalid string you will get an exception. You can solve this by using the `.TryParse()` method or encapsulate the thing in Try-Catch. I would recommend `.TryParse()`, though because it's more optimized and generally viewed a more correct way of doing this.